# nestable2 expand button not hiding when list expanded

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I'm trying to implement nestable2.js in a .net core mvc app and i'm unable to make the expand button hidden when the list is expanded. However the list does expand and collapse as expected.

It appears that the button class "dd-expand" is not modified when the element is modified.

```
        <div class="cf nestable-lists">
        <div class="dd" id="nestable">
            <ol class="dd-list">
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 1</div>
                </li>
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="2">
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 2</div>
                </li>
                <li class="dd-item dd-collapsed" data-id="3">
                    <button class="dd-collapse" data-action="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button>
                    <button class="dd-expand" data-action="expand" type="button">Expand</button>
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 3</div>
                    <ol class="dd-list">
                        <li class="dd-item" data-id="4">
                            <div class="dd-handle">Item 4</div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dd-item" data-id="5" data-foo="bar">
                            <div class="dd-nodrag">Item 5</div>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Screengrab of the issue at hand:

(Dropdown fully expanded)
[image]

(Dropdown fully collapsed)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Which version of nestable2 you are using ? I use the [CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/nestable2) ：

```
<div class="cf nestable-lists">
<div class="dd" id="nestable">
    <ol class="dd-list">
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
            <div class="dd-handle">Item 1</div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="2">
            <div class="dd-handle">Item 2</div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item dd-collapsed" data-id="3">
            <button class="dd-collapse" data-action="collapse" type="button">Collapse</button>
            <button class="dd-expand" data-action="expand" type="button">Expand</button>
            <div class="dd-handle">Item 3</div>
            <ol class="dd-list">
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="4">
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 4</div>
                </li>
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="5" data-foo="bar">
                    <div class="dd-nodrag">Item 5</div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

```
@section Scripts{

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nestable2/1.6.0/jquery.nestable.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('.dd').nestable({ /* config options */ });
</script>

}
```

It hides the expand button when the list is expanded :

[image]